# How to get datagrid to show in toolbox

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am new to wfp and am looking for the datagrid tool, how do I add it to the toolbox.  I have checked in the options and it all appears checked etc.

Thanks, R.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is in .Net version of project. 3.5 .Net does not support DataGrid in wpf, so, to solve this problem just change .net version of project. For example choose .net 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Right Click the Toolbox. Select "Choose Items...". In the WPF Components Tab, in the Filter Textbox type DataGrid. From there you can add it to the Toolbox.

Comment: DataGrid is not in the list, why is that?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Yes 3.5 does not support wpfg windows controls just change project .net version to 4.0 and check.

Comment: Is your answer significantly different from the [upvoted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19942120/5488275)? If not, please consider removing yours (as it doesn't add anything).